# phonegap's nfc plugin object is throwing exception in one of my javascript file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am using cordova + react js
As part of implementing NFC (Near Field communication) I have downloaded phonegap-nfc plugin
But when I tried to use phonegap's nfc plugin object variable, throwing exception in one of my javascript file. like (import nfc from 'phonegap-nfc/www/phonegap-nfc';)
Error received is:

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'cordova/exec' in 'D:\GIT\lockers-app-ret
ail-wf_latest\node_modules\phonegap-nfc\www'

**Related code given in below**

handleNFCPopup = () =>{
console.log("hello jb you are in NFC pop up...");

```
// Read NDEF formatted NFC Tags
nfc.addNdefListener (
    (nfcEvent) =>{
        var tag = nfcEvent.tag,
            ndefMessage = tag.ndefMessage;

        // dump the raw json of the message
        // note: real code will need to decode
        // the payload from each record
        alert(JSON.stringify(ndefMessage));

        // assuming the first record in the message has
        // a payload that can be converted to a string.
        alert(nfc.bytesToString(ndefMessage[0].payload).substring(3));
    },
     () => { // success callback
        alert("Waiting for NDEF tag");
    },
    (error) =>{ // error callback
        alert("Error adding NDEF listener " + JSON.stringify(error));
    }
);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Cordova, and installed the plugin with `cordova plugin add phonegap-nfc`, Cordova will create a global variable `nfc` (or `window.nfc` if you prefer.) You should not need to import `phonegap-nfc.js` yourself. That file isn't really a module until the Cordova tools wrap it. Also, make sure that you don't call any functions on `nfc` until Cordova's `deviceready` event fires.

Answer (score 0):

doncoleman's answer is excellent, I'll just add that to make sure you don't call any functions on nfc before Cordova's deviceready event, you can replace, in `index.tsx`, this line:

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

with this:

```
document.addEventListener(
    "deviceready",
    () => ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root")),
    false
);
```

More about React + NFC + Capacitor or Cordova in this article:
https://medium.com/@zwyx/nfc-on-android-with-react-and-typescript-using-capacitor-or-cordova-b525dba5f620